# Вызов виртуальной функции С++

Tags: c++

```
class Receiver:public Task
{
...
private:    //override
    long                    Process();

private:
...
};

long Receiver::Process()
{
...
}

class Task{                                             
    ...                             
private:
    ...
    virtual long        Process()=0;
...
};  

inline Task *   Task::TaskExec(Thread *ThisThread)
{
...
    long l_retval   =-10000;
...
    try{l_retval =Process();}catch(...){} // ?
...
}
```

Не понимаю как вызывается функция Receiver::Process() в проекте. Искал через (ctrl+shift+f), нашел только использование в Task::TaskExec(). Разве можно вызывать функцию Process(), которая виртуальная(=0)?

Comment: Класс Receiver наследует функцию TaskExec от абстрактного класса Task, и в ней вызывается переопределенная виртуальная функция для объекта класса Receiver Я надеюсь, что функция TaskExec - не статическая функция?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так (см. комментарии). Более-менее понятно или нужно пояснять подробнее?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void vf() = 0;
    void func()
    {
        // Здесь вызывается vf() КОНКРЕТНОГО класса, с
        // использованием т.н. позднего связывания
        vf();
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    // Перекрытая виртуальная функция
    void vf()
    {
        cout << "In Derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Здесь b, будучи указателем на Base, указывает на объект Derived
    Base * b = new Derived;

    // Вступает в игру позднее связывание. В вызове func выясняется,
    // на что именно указывает b, и внутри вызывается vf() этого объекта.
    b->func();
}
```

Кстати, чисто виртуальная функция может иметь тело и быть вызываема:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void vf() = 0
    {
        cout << "In Base\n";
    }
    void func()
    {
        vf();
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void vf()
    {
        Base::vf();
        cout << "In Derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base * b = new Derived;
    b->func();
}
```